# SO Meta-tags : Question vs Programming problem

Tags: feature-request

If I'm not mistaken, SO questions are likely to be split in 2 categories (maybe 3-4 depends on abstraction layers - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) :

**("Real") Questions :**

- Why XXX is done / handled that way in XXXXX language ?
- How to use XXXXXX design pattern in YYYYY cases ?
- It is possible to do XXXXX with YYYYY ?

Which are more likely to be generic, get extended answers and high views / votes. (Basically, everything in https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes follows these patterns)

**Programming problems :**

- How can I do this particular thing in XXXX ?
- My code gives the following error XXXXX
- How to get that OUTPUT with this INPUT ?

Most questions fall here : specific questions related to particular piece of code in a particular context.

---

In the same way Meta StackOverflow has "meta-tags" (Discussion, Support, Feature-Request, Bug) that you MUST use, could such meta-tags (Programming question, Coding problem, Coding error, ...) be useful to SO ?

(Note : Probably a duplicate, but since I don't know how these "meta-tags" are truly named, I couldn't find any. Bonus point if you can't tell me their real generic name if they've one)

Comment: We do not seem to have the same idea about what makes a "real" question. To me, questions like *Why XXX is done / handled that way in XXXXX language?* or *It is possible to do XXXXX with YYYYY?* are strong candidates to closure, not good questions.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi By "real" questions, I meant questions with a much more justified question mark, which is, as you stated, different from "good" questions as of SO rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have, in fact, been eliminating "meta" tags from SO for quite a while.

They are not generally useful for SO. We end up with tags that are appropriate to a very large number of questions, but that don't add any value to it.

We end up with questions tagged with these generic tags, but that are of no interest to most people who view them.

It is much better to have sets of much more focused tags.